# Using private method in lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, methods, lambda

I am working on the logic handle and got this trouble. If I use this code, it's not working:

```
private bool CheckDateTimeIsValid(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, DateTime dateTime)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(startTime, dateTime) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(endTime, dateTime) >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var listChallengeUsers = _context.ChallengeUseres
            .Where(cu => cu.AppUserId == activity.AppUserId)
            .Where(cu => cu.Challenge.ActivityType == activity.Type)
            .Where(cu => CheckDateTimeIsValid(cu.Challenge.StartTime, cu.Challenge.EndTime, activity.CreatedAt))
```

But if I use this, it worked:

```
var listChallengeUsers = _context.ChallengeUseres
            .Where(cu => cu.AppUserId == activity.AppUserId)
            .Where(cu => cu.Challenge.ActivityType == activity.Type)
            .Where(cu => DateTime.Compare(cu.Challenge.StartTime, activity.CreatedAt) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(cu.Challenge.EndTime, activity.CreatedAt) >= 0 )
            .ToList();
```

Can someone help's me to know why it happen and how to use in the first way?

Comment: What error/issue you are getting in first code it seems good to me. You can make your private function short by just returning `return (DateTime.Compare(startTime, dateTime) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(endTime, dateTime) >= 0)` no need of if condition

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What's the error reported?

Comment: is your ``var listChallengeUsers = _context.ChallengeUseres in a static method? Because `CheckDateTimeIsValid` is not static and cannot be invoked?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I added static to  ```CheckDateTimeIsValid ``` but it still not working

Comment: @scharnyw it returns null for the query while it should be an array which has one element inside

Comment: My feeling is you are using EF / EF Core and building database queries? Was your error saying function cannot be translated?

Comment: @weichch I didn't get any error in Debug mode, it's weird, it just went wrong when returns null while it shouldn't. Yes, I'm using EF Core to building queries.

Comment: Weird. I don't think EF supports local functions in queries. But you'd get an exception saying method cannot be translated. For testing purpose, add `AsEnumerable()` after `.Where(cu => cu.Challenge.ActivityType == activity.Type)` and see if you get the same results?

Comment: @ThanhHải In the code where it works, u have .ToList (), which returns list of found elements and can be accessed as array. But in the code where it doesn't work, u don't have .ToList (), so u get an enumerator instead, which can't be accessed as an array. Try calling .ToList() in ur first code.

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't marked as "static", so either call it via instance or mark the method as static, like this:

```
private static bool CheckDateTimeIsValid ( DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, DateTime dateTime )
{
    if (DateTime.Compare ( startTime, dateTime ) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare ( endTime, dateTime ) >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, your code can be shorter like this:

```
static bool CheckDateTimeIsValid ( DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, DateTime dateTime ) => startTime <= dateTime && dateTime <= endTime;
```

And if u decide the method to be static, then it makes more sense to put this method as an extension, if u will use this method often in different places:

```
public static class DateTimeExts
{
    public static bool CheckDateTimeIsValid ( this DateTime dateTime, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime ) => startTime <= dateTime && dateTime <= endTime;
}
```

Comment: I called it inside a class, both functions are inside one class. Even I add static to my private method, it still not working :(